# Is there a user-level utility which offers the features of "cron" or "at" and only within a particular session?

Tags: cron, software-rec, scheduling, at, non-root-user

I want to run a some scheduled commands on a timed basis within a manually started`screen` session and only within that `screen` session, because it uses an ssh authentication tied to that session.

Basically it means that after I start the screen session, I add the ssh key for the session then I start the command, so all the subsequent commands run by the utility have access to the remote resources made availabe by the key.

When the session is terminated then it all ends.

`at` and `cron` seem to be configured by `root` but I want a user-level program running within my own account and directories.

Comment: If you're running a systemd-based distro, take a look at **systemd-run**: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-run.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asking around led me to [supercronic](https://github.com/aptible/supercronic) which is described by its developers as

> a crontab-compatible job runner, designed specifically to run in
> containers.

Although it was designed with containers in mind it works as a regular user program and can use `crontab` format files for scheduling and running tasks.